# Transformer-insulated flame ionization detector. How to improve response? Triode, messure current safety, ignition fires

Tags: detector, ionization

I am trying to do a isolate flame ionization detector with a transformer ignition. But, when I put it on the frame, nothing change.. (0.2VAC)

I put a amplifier (10 teraohms impedance) to read the signal too, but it is the same of the osciloscope.

If the probe touch the ground of my house, it messuare 5 VAC, with nice senoid (or shorted too);

*: The transformer is the same used to ignition. Primary 230 VAC and Secondary 8KV
 Please, what is possible to do for improve more sensibility/response at Primary? I put one source 300VA by another transformer to produce elétrons, but the triode frame don´t work as expected.

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but this is a bad way to make a flame detector- soot or moisture leakage from the rod can act the same as the flame, which in turn can lead to massive explosions destroying buildings and such like.

Comment: Thanks Spehro. Yes, but in normal mode, the read value not is maximum.